# Compare a string using sh shell

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am using SH shell and I am trying to compare a string with a variable's value but the `if` condition is always execute to true. Why?

Here is some code:

```
Sourcesystem="ABC"

if [ "$Sourcesystem" -eq 'XYZ' ]; then 
    echo "Sourcesystem Matched" 
else
    echo "Sourcesystem is NOT Matched $Sourcesystem"  
fi;

echo Sourcesystem Value is  $Sourcesystem ;
```

Even this is not working:

```
Sourcesystem="ABC"

if [ 'XYZ' -eq "$Sourcesystem" ]; then 
    echo "Sourcesystem Matched" 
else
    echo "Sourcesystem is NOT Matched $Sourcesystem"  
fi;

echo Sourcesystem Value is  $Sourcesystem ;
```

Secondly, can we match this with a NULL or empty string?

Comment: First in Bourne shell you don't need the extra ';'  When I test run the script in Bourne shell, the if condition is false. It will first give an warning: [: ABC: integer expression expected.  The output is: "Sourcesystem is NOT Matched ABC".  As commented by others, -eq is used for integer comparisons.  Use a single equal sign for string comparison in Bourne shell (#!/bin/sh). Your shell should have corrected you in the first place.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The cited dups are for bash shell, not the anemic sh shell which is sometimes a Posix shell or Dash.

Comment: Agreed and so voted.  `sh` and `bash` bear the same relationship as `C` and `C++`.  Even though code written for the first is valid in the second, answers for the second can't be trusted to work in the first.

Answer (score 382):

You should use the `=` operator for string comparison:

```
Sourcesystem="ABC"

if [ "$Sourcesystem" = "XYZ" ]; then 
    echo "Sourcesystem Matched" 
else
    echo "Sourcesystem is NOT Matched $Sourcesystem"  
fi;
```

`man test` says that you use `-z` to match for empty strings.

Comment: It is not necessary to quote `ABC` or `XYZ`.

Comment: If your variable might have spaces in it then quoting is necessary.

Comment: Adjusted the example to make that part clearer @WilliamEverett.

Comment: This method doesn't work with sh nor bash (macOS 11.2) if both strings contain multiple lines, where the first line is equal but further lines are different - then I get always true for a `=` test. With macOS' new zsh, however, I can even leave the quotes out, as in `[ $a = $b ]`, and get the correct result for multi-line strings.

Comment: @Thomas - the OP question is specifically about `sh` not bash or zsh. OP examples would also never me multi-line strings. Multi-line strings should probably take a different approach rather than rely on a feature of zsh, unless you are working in an exclusively zsh environment. Targeting `sh` usually means you need high portability because bash and/or zsh isn't available in all of your environments. I'm on macOS and could target zsh, but then when my scripts are moved to linux system over which I have no control they will fail due to zsh not being present.

Answer (score 98):

`-eq` is used to compare integers. Use `=` instead.

Comment: And pay attention to not use double equal "=="

Answer (score 54):

eq is used to compare integers use equal '=' instead , 
example:

```
if [ 'AAA' = 'ABC' ];
then 
    echo "the same" 
else 
    echo "not the same"
fi
```

good luck

Comment: Note: if you're comparing variables, make sure you use `"$VAR"` and not simply `$VAR`

Comment: Also note that if you are comparing a variable to a string `[ $(VAR) = "ABC" ]`

Answer (score 33):

I had this same problem, do this

```
if [ 'xyz' = 'abc' ]; then
  echo "match"
fi
```

Notice the whitespace. It is important that you use a whitespace in this case after and before the `=` sign.

Check out "[Other Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)".

Comment: in Dockerfile: /bin/sh: 1: [: =: unexpected operator

Comment: You linked to documentation for bash, the OP asked about /bin/sh.

Answer (score 12):

`-eq` is the shell comparison operator for comparing integers. For comparing strings you need to use `=`.

Answer (score 3):

`-eq` is a mathematical comparison operator.  I've never used it for string comparison, relying on `==` and `!=` for compares.

```
if [ 'XYZ' == 'ABC' ]; then   # Double equal to will work in Linux but not on HPUX boxes it should be if [ 'XYZ' = 'ABC' ] which will work on both
  echo "Match"
else
  echo "No Match"
fi
```

Comment: Note that the operator `==` does not work on every shell. `=` is the correct operator to use in order to compare strings, and `==` is sometimes a synonym.

Comment: This answer is **wrong** for /bin/sh scripts and will fail. On macOS, the "test" command (also available as "[") treats "="" as "=". On Linux it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Of the 4 shells that I've tested,  `ABC -eq XYZ` evaluates to true in the `test` builtin for `zsh` and `ksh`.   The expression evaluates to false under `/usr/bin/test` and the builtins for `dash` and `bash`.  In `ksh` and `zsh`, the strings are converted to numerical values and are equal since they are both 0.  IMO, the behavior of the builtins for `ksh` and `zsh` is incorrect, but the spec for `test` is ambiguous on this.

Comment: Thanks for testing.  That's why Bourne shell is popular.

Comment: **zsh** clearly outputs _: integer expression expected_
after using **[** or builtin **test**.  Maybe you are forcing *[[* which evaluates both as 0 as strings are **not** significant integers.

Comment: @code933k Which version?  I wouldn't be surprised if the behavior has changed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell zsh 5.7.1