# String comparison in bash. [[: not found

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-11.04, string-comparison

I am trying to compare strings in bash. I already found an answer on how to do it on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash). In script I am trying, I am using the code submitted by Adam in the mentioned question:

```
#!/bin/bash
string='My string';

if [[ "$string" == *My* ]]
then
  echo "It's there!";
fi

needle='y s'
if [[ "$string" == *"$needle"* ]]; then
  echo "haystack '$string' contains needle '$needle'"
fi
```

I also tried approach from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=562398) that you can find in 2nd post

```
if [[ $var =~ regexp ]]; then
  #do something
fi
```

In both cases I receive error:

```
[[: not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I might do it wrong, but using a single square bracket always worked for me.

Comment: What does `/bin/bash --version` print?

Comment: `[` won't work in this case, because it doesn't support patterns.

Comment: This generally means you ran `sh yourscript` instead of `bash yourscript`; the `#!/bin/bash` shebang doesn't do anything if you override it by using `sh`.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

`[[` is a bash-builtin. Your `/bin/bash` doesn't seem to be an actual bash.

*From a comment:*

Add `#!/bin/bash` at the top of file

Comment: if I type: type '[[' i get [[ is a shell keyword

Comment: Do you get the same result when you run `/bin/bash -c "type [["`?

Comment: This happened to me because I forgot to add `#!/bin/bash` at the top of my file

Comment: Happend to me because i ran the script with `sh`, lots for frustration. Now i just have to redo everything i undid before finding this answer.

Comment: It is really important that `#!/bin/bash` is on the 1st line. I generated a script that accidentally started with a new line which made this problem difficult to find.

Answer (score 221):

How you are running your script?
If you did with

```
$ sh myscript
```

you should try:

```
$ bash myscript
```

or, if the script is executable:

```
$ ./myscript
```

*sh* and *bash* are two [different shells](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/shell-differences/). While in the first case you are passing your script as an argument to the sh interpreter, in the second case you decide on the very first line which interpreter will be used.

Comment: i got permission denied this way. with sudo ./myscript its command not found

Comment: do **chmod +x myscript**, then run again, you don't need sudo

Comment: How you are invoking you script?

Comment: like you said. normally i call it with '$sh myscipt.sh'. 2nd time after doing chmod +x myscript.sh i called it with ./myscript.sh

Comment: The error is expected when you run the script via `sh myscript.sh`, because `/bin/sh` emulates a Bourne shell where `[[` is not a builtin. However, running the script via `./script.sh` should not yield an error, because in that case the shebang should cause `/bin/bash` to be used.

Comment: See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](/q//5725296) which elaborates on the differences.

Answer (score 85):

Is the first line in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
```

the sh shell produces this error messages, not bash

Comment: First line was also missing for me producing the error the author mentioned!

Answer (score 28):

As @Ansgar mentioned, `[[` is a bashism, ie built into Bash and not available for other shells. If you want your script to be portable, use `[`. Comparisons will also need a different syntax: change `==` to `=`.

```sh
if [ $MYVAR = "myvalue" ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Comment: Checked a bit with Ubuntu 16.04 and (sh ->) dash 0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2 and found that [ works fine in combination with "-eq" and alikes. Similar information on comparison operators for this context can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849297/compare-a-string-using-sh-shell - I further cheked with (( )) evaluation operator as recommended in the next link but that seemed to fail for my minimal invasive changes /or/ it would need a much deeper level of code changes. http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Control_structures/comparison_operators.shtml

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem when installing [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone)

This is how I solved the problem

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 ago 15  2012 /bin/sh -> dash
```

As you can see, /bin/sh is a link to "dash" (not bash), and `[[` is bash syntactic sugarness. So I just replaced the link to /bin/bash. **Careful using rm like this in your system!**

```
$ sudo rm /bin/sh
$ sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Comment: Overriding the default `sh` for your distro is ill-advised IMHO.  A shell which is run with `sh` should work with `dash`; if it doesn't, that's a bug in the script.  If you need `bash` features, use `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: this sounds terrible tbh

Comment: I agree, it was just an ugly workaround. A similar but better workaround would be to use `update-alternatives` (in debian-based-linux) like this https://justinconover.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/ubuntu-changing-dash-to-bash/ but in the end, it would be the same.

Answer (score 10):

If you know you're on bash, and still get this error, make sure you write the if with spaces.

```
[[1==1]] # This outputs error

[[ 1==1 ]] # OK
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify bash instead of sh when running the script. I personally noticed they are different under ubuntu 12.10:

`bash script.sh arg0 ... argn`

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 3):

Execute in your terminal:

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/sh sh /bin/bash 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the file executable and then execute without sh.

1. make it executable by $ chmod +x filename
2. then instead of sh filename  use ./filename

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (on a Mac) – but due to the fact, that I entered a space before the "[" with the option key already down for typing the "[". So the space character was not the space character I wanted to type, but a "nonbreaking space". Not visible in the text editor – but caused a "[[ : command not found" error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34638384)