# More Bash Problems [if statements always evaluating to false.]

Tags: bash

Warninng: This may be a  specific machine issue or a problem with GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) will update as I check further.

Update 1: Works with GNU bash, version 4.2.39. and GNU bash, version 4.2.24

I am working on bash script that asks questions. I was hoping to have a wild card if statement but checks if the user enters in no or just n but for some reason it just does not seem to work.

```
echo 'Is this a Personal Project? [y/n]'
    read ORG_SWITCH
echo 'Do you want to Open Source this project? [y/n]'
    read PRIVATE
```

and here is the if statement

```
if [[ $ORG_SWITCH == *"n"* ]] ; then
    if [[ $PRIVATE == *"n"* ]] ; then
```

the errors it outputs are [[: not found [[: not found

and I am not sure why. I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/bash-how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement) but and tried a few of the solutions there but maybe I am just not understanding what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated and please feel free to talk down.

Comment: do you start your script with `#!/bin/bash`? (if you don't, maybe another kind of `sh` is used to run it, having no built-in `[[`?)

Comment: The script has that at the top. It is actually just to long to post the entire thing. But the simplified script below also never validates so I am tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read -n1 -p "Is this a Personal Project? [y/n] " ORG_SWITCH` to avoid using the `echo` and to limit the user input to one char (`y` or `n`). Also you can test your condition without the `[[ ]]` pair:

```
read -n1 -p "Is this a Personal Project? [y/n] " ORG_SWITCH 
read -n1 -p "Do you want to Open Source this project? [y/n] " PRIVATE

if [ "$ORG_SWITCH" = "n" ]; then 
    if [ "$PRIVATE" = "n" ]; then 
        echo "double no"
    fi
fi
```

In one bracket conditions (`[ ]`), always double quote your variables, so if they evaluate to empty, your code won't incur in a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This code works on `GNU bash, version 4.2.24`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Is this a Personal Project? [y/n]'
read ORG_SWITCH

if [[ $ORG_SWITCH == *"n"* ]] ; then
    echo "True $ORG_SWITCH"
else
    echo "False $ORG_SWITCH"
fi

echo 'Do you want to Open Source this project? [y/n]'
read PRIVATE
if [[ $PRIVATE == *"n"* ]] ; then
    echo "True $PRIVATE"
else
    echo "False $PRIVATE"
fi
```

This is the output

```
Is this a Personal Project? [y/n]
no
True no
Do you want to Open Source this project? [y/n]
no
True no
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Tested this and get the same response, as in my exception in GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). I just assumed it was my code because normally I am the weak chain in the link.

Comment: Also it could be that you are not [*actually* running bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12230756/828193). You are executing the script with `./scriptname.sh` right?

Comment: Yep just tested on a fresh VM.GNU bash, version 4.2.39. Will keep posting updates till I get to the bottom of it.