# Linux "-sh: 25: [[: not found" not being logged into user when using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

When I SSH into the server, I'm not being fully logged in. What I mean by this, is that if I use `whoami`, it displays my account. However, my .bashrc never gets initiated. My terminal also looks like:

`-sh: 25: [[: not found
$`

Once I `su` into the account, everything works fine, and my terminal shows:

`user@ip-000-00-00-000:~$`

What's causing this?

Comment: Are you sourcing your `.bashrc` in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`)? It looks like you either have an error in your remote `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String comparison in bash. \[\[: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230690/string-comparison-in-bash-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your login shell is `sh`, a simpler shell with fewer features. You can change it to `bash` with `chsh`.

Comment: That fits the bill.

Comment: Nice. Needed to set bash as the default shell too: `sudo usermod -s /bin/bash user`