# Inconsistent result using bash script through shell vs cron

Tags: bash, cron

I've got the following bash script to check if a string length is nonzero using **-n** and equals "OK" by converting the variable to uppercase using **${1^^}**:

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunction() {
    result=0
    if [[ -n $1 && ${1^^} = "OK" ]]; then
            result=1
    fi
    echo $result >> /home/[REDACTED]/mylog
}
myfunction "ok"
myfunction "NO"
```

I made it executable using:

```
sudo chmod +x ./test
```

I then call it with either of the following:

```
bash ./test
./test
```

And the file always contains the expected result:

```
1
0
```

However, when trying to run from cron and the file contains:

```
0
0
```

I set up cron with this command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And here is the content:

```
* * * * * /home/[REDACTED]/test
```

I'm probably overlooking something obvious like syntax or cron environment... any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the shell `cron` runs is `bash` ? By default cron is configured tu use `/bin/sh` which behaves differently than bash

Comment: Sounds likely... How would I check?

Edit: I updated cron to this but made no difference:

    * * * * * /bin/bash -c "/home/[REDACTED]/test"

Comment: After reading this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230690/string-comparison-in-bash-not-found/12230723) I tried "sh ./test" and got "[[: not found" so it does seem cron is executing as sh not bash.

Comment: are you using a mac by any chance ? if so, `/bin/bash` is bash 3.2, which doesn't recognize the `${1^^}` syntax

Comment: No, and apologies I should have stated my environment: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Comment: Still, it might be that it runs an old bash version on cron.  Try to print `echo $BASH_VERSION $1  ${1^^} $result >> /home/[REDACTED]/mylog` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but deleting the first line of the file and retyping has resolved it:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Thanks all for the help!