# Unexpected operator - shell script in a Bamboo plan

Tags: shell, bamboo

I try to run shell command in my Bamboo plan.
This is my code I try to run:

`[ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *test* ] || [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *develop* ] && echo "yes"`

That should check branch name is `test` or `develop`. If it is, then it should print message `yes`.

I run this on branch `develop`, then I got error.

Error message:
`[: develop: unexpected operator`

---

UPDATE:

This is POSIX so based on a post:
[String comparison in bash. [[: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230690/string-comparison-in-bash-not-found/37528631)
I replaced `==` with a single `=`.

So my command looks:

`[ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = *test* ] || [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = *develop* ] && echo "yes"`

Error messaage I got:
`[: pytest.ini: unexpected operator`

No idea what is pytest.ini is doing here.
My application using pytest but in this step I didn't run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with single brackets is that the wildcards are expanded through the filename expansion (globbing). Consider this:

```sh
$ touch test{1,2,3,4}
$ set -x
$ [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *"test"* ] || [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *"develop"* ] && echo "yes"
$ [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *"test"* ]
++ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
+ '[' develop == test1 test2 test3 test4 ']'
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

If you have double brackets available in your shell, then you might replace single brackets with double brackets:

```sh
[[ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *"test"* ]] \
    || [[ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" == *"develop"* ]] && echo "yes"
```

As an alternative, you might use `case` as follows:

```sh
case "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" in
    *test*|*develop*)
        echo 'yes'
        ;;
esac
```

---

Note, single opening bracket (`[`) is just a synonym for the `test` builtin with the only exception that the single opening bracket requires the last argument to be `]`.

Comment: I try it, it also generate error: ` [[: not found `

Comment: @CezarySzulc, then double brackets could be unavailable in your shell. Consider using `case` (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Slightly surprisingly, you don't need quotes around the argument to `case`.

Comment: I used `case` and it works fine. Thanks