# Shell script substring extraction and manipulation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I was able to extract a substring from a string; but no matter what syntax changes I try (and I've tried many), I am unable to actually enter the `if` block in this snippet even though the print out suggests that the `CLIENT_NAME` string matches the expected one (attached the output from the first `echo`). Only the first `echo` prints anything. What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas are really appreciated!

The idea is if the client is named say `aa_NNNN`, then I need to extract the `aa` and the `NNNN` and check if the `aa` matches a known string (say "`xx`") and if it does, only then, calculate the version `NNNN` and do something if version `NNNN` exceeds a known version `MMMM`.

```
#! /bin/sh
CLIENT=$1
...
CLIENT_NAME="${CLIENT:0:2}"
CLIENT_VERSION=2015
echo "Before compare; client: $CLIENT_NAME; version: $CLIENT_VERSION"
if [ "$CLIENT_NAME" == "xx" ]; then
   CLIENT_VERSION="${CLIENT:3:4}"
   echo "Inside compare; client: $CLIENT_NAME; version: $CLIENT_VERSION"
   if [ $CLIENT_VERSION -ge 2016 ]; then
      ...
   fi
fi
```

First echo output:

```
Before compare; client: xx; version: 2015
```

`/bin/sh --version` returns:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. Are you doing something with the var ```CLIENT``` in the code you suppress?

Comment: @anubhava: That's a command line argument input to the script. I know CLIENT is getting the right input. To be precise the $1 in this case is xx_2016

Comment: @tiagohngl: Oh wow.. no nothing at all in those suppressed lines. So you got the inside echo to also print? That's insane!

Comment: Well, executing the script like this ```script.sh xx_2016``` works for the first if. In the last if you have to replace ```,``` with ```:```

Comment: Have you tried using bash instead of sh (```/bin/bash```)? In most systems it points to the same binary, but it maybe be the problem

Comment: Good point. I did have a typo there with the `,` instead of `:`. Going to correct it now. But the issue still remains for me.. I'll try /bin/bash as you suggest.

Comment: Your output doesn't quite match the `echo` statement in your script. Could you fix that?

Comment: Fixed...good catch. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same result running your code, but removing the quotes from the substring extraction (and replacing the `,` with `:` in the second one) fixed it...

```
CLIENT_NAME=${CLIENT:0:2}
```

...and...

```
CLIENT_VERSION=${CLIENT:3:4}
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick: Did you have /bin/bash just like @tiagohngl? I tried with your changes and still the second echo doesn't print for me.

Comment: I'm on a Mac with GNU Bash 3.2.57. The edited script works for me with `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh`. I also tested successfully on Ubuntu 14.04 with Bash (`/bin/bash`).

Comment: Have you tried changing the "shebang" line to Bash at the top of your script?  `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Yes, did that too.. still don't see the inside echo. No error message, nothing.

Comment: Is there a value for `$CLIENT_NAME` in the first echo? And how are you invoking the script? What's the actual command you're using? And what is the output of `which bash`?

Comment: Yes, the first echo prints out as expected (I displayed the output in my question) - it shows as `xx`. I am invoking it by executing from command line with argument as follows: `scriptname xx_2016`, so I am expecting to see the version displayed as `2016` in the inner echo, but I don't even see the inner echo printed. `which bash` returns: `/bin/bash`

Comment: When I read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849297/compare-a-string-in-unix, it seems to suggest using `=` instead of `==`. Could that be the problem? Does using `=` even make any sense? Even the responses in that link are quite confusing.

Comment: The Bash scripting guide for Linux says that `==` is a synonym for `=`, but you could try it.  Ref: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Tried that too.. still doesn't print the inner echo for me.

Comment: Apparently I had another typo that I finally caught. I am marking this as the answer. Apologies, and thanks all for your help!

Comment: No problem. Typos go with the territory in Bash. :)